# typed observables with Angular HTTP

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs, observable

short: *Having a method that returns a http call (get, put, whatever), determine the type of the items returned, using typescript types?*

On TypeScrpt level, a promise is a generic type. It carries on the type of the message you expect, e.g. `IPromise<T>`. This way you can define that a method returns a promise of type `Promise<number[]>` which basically returns a promise that resolves with a list of numbers. Thanks to this, you make typescript even more powerful.

You can do the same with Observables (RxJS). Simple, we've got `Observable<T>` (just take a look at `Observable.d.ts` in npm:`rxjs`). Each item you expect in this stream is of type T (this is the `subscribe` callback parameter - has to be - TypeScript checks this for you).

### Angular

Going back to Angular, the HTTP module wraps Observables. It doesn't return values immediately, but emits http calls with HTTP-related stuff (status, status text, url, etc), not just the value. In http's .d.ts, http.get, put, post, etc return `Observable<Response>`, where `Response` is the Angular built-in wrapper for HTTP call. But I see *I lose the possibility to predefine the type of what a HTTP is supposed to return.*

question is: *is there a possibility in angular http calls to predefine what type is the http-call/observable return?* Something like `Observable<User>` where `User` is just my application interface.

Comment: Why don't you use the framework as it is, and type it after your calls ? For instance, I type it in my services, with classes I created in the frontend

Comment: @trichetriche not interested in subjective opinions. If you haven't used typed promises or typed observables before angular 2+ then you're not aware of what you're missing.

Comment: Take a look here : https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter/blob/master/src/app/shared/states/pizzas/pizzas.service.ts#L23 I think you want something like that

Comment: @Maxime exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

get(id: number): Observable<User> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http
               .get(url)
               .do((response: Response) => {
                 if (!response) {
                   return Observable.of(null);
                 }
               })
               .map((response: Response) => {
                   return <User>response.json();
               })
               .catch(error => {
                 return Observable.of(null);
               });
}
```

Comment: seems like just a wrapper. But in order to be used as a DAO method, I'd just remove `.catch` (client component can handle that). Makes sense, thanks

Comment: yes, it is basically a wrapper and you could genericize it. you could remove the catch, but it would provide a way to handle the errors consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone...

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersModel {
  getItem(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/users/${id}`, {
      headers: this.getHeaders()
    });
  }
}
```

In above code the error thrown is that `Observable<Response>` is in conflict with `Observable<User>`, distinct data types. The solution is just to include the `observable.map((res) => res.json())` into the DAO method like here:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersModel {
  getItem(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/users/${id}`, {
      headers: this.getHeaders()
    })
    .map((res) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Now there's no conflict, since `res.json` (of class Response) returns `any`. And this open the possibility for us to make `getItem` method return certain type of ours: `getItem(id: number): Observable<User>`. And I've got what I need - outside the DAO - in a component, for instance, I do:

```
this.UsersModel.getItem().subscribe(u => {
  u // u is of User already, yay!
})
```